# How do I change my for loops to while loops?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I wrote a program using for loops but instead of for loops I want to write them as while loops.

```
def print_stacks(n, stacks):
    #loop through each disk
    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        #loop through each stack
        for stack in stacks:
            #if current disk is in the surrent stack then print
            if i < len(stack):
                print(stack[i], end=" ")
```

I am stuck on what i should do

Comment: Why? Is this an educational exercise / homework assignment?

Comment: While it's always *possible* to turn a `for` loop into a `while` loop, it doesn't always (or even often) make the code better. Without an explanation of what this code is doing (and what the input values mean), I don't think we can help you make the code *better* with while loops. Razi Melliti's answer does the literal thing you're asking for, but that code is worse than what you already have, using `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

same code using while loops :

```
def print_stacks(n, stacks):
    i = n - 1
    while i >= 0:
        j = 0
        while j < len(stacks):
            if i < len(stacks[j]):
                print(stacks[j][i], end=" ")
            j += 1
        i -= 1
    print()
```